# Using older torch version in conda environment not working

Tags: python, pytorch, conda, slurm, virtual-environment

Can anyone please help me?
I am trying to run a .py script for which I need an older pytorch version, because a function I am using is deprecated in later torch versions. But I seem not to be able to install it correctly.

I installed torch into my virtual environment using

`conda create -n my_env python=3.6.2`

`source activate my_env`

`conda install pytorch==1.7.0 torchvision==0.8.0 torchaudio==0.7.0 cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch`

Then I have a python file (**myfile.py**) that I start using a shell file (**start.sh**). The files are on a SLURM-cluster, so I start start.sh with `sbatch start.sh`.

**start.sh**

`source activate my_env`

`srun --unbuffered python myfile.py`

**myfile.py**

`import torch`

`print(torch.__version__)`

The print command from myfile.py still returns "1.8.0", but using `conda list` in my environment shows "1.7.0" for pytorch version.

Even when I type `python -c "import torch; print(torch.__version__)"` directly into terminal, it will return "1.8.0" (rather than "1.7.0" from `conda list`)

Am I doing something very obvious wrong possibly? Did I install in a wrong way, or is somehow my environment not properly loaded in the python file?

Best regards and thanks a lot in advance

Comment: How do you run `start.sh`? Have you tried `source start.sh`?

Comment: `srun` - is this on SLURM? maybe you should have an HPC or SLURM tag

Comment: Yes it is on SLURM. That's why I have to start start.sh with ```sbatch start.sh```. I thought that wasnt core of the problem, so I left it out. 

I added it to the post!

Comment: Did you already check which `python` interpreter `srun` actually uses? I am suspecting that `srun` does not use the activated conda env. Can you try `srun --unbuffered conda run -n my_env python myfile.py`?

Comment: Hi FlyingTeller,
I think you could be right because that would explain the problem. 
However when I try substituting ```srun --unbuffered python myfile.py``` as you proposed with 
```srun --unbuffered conda run -n my_env python myfile.py```
an error is thrown:
ERROR conda.cli.main_run:execute(33): Subprocess for 'conda run ['python', 'myfile.py']' command failed.

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that installing the environment as described added a link to another python installation to my PYTHONPATH (a link to /.local/python) and that directory was added to PYTHONPATH in a higher order than the python used in my environment (/anaconda/env/my_env/python/...) .
Therefore, the local version of python was used instead.

I could not delete it from PYTHONPATH either, but changing the directory name to /.local/_python did the trick.

It's not pretty, but it works.

Thanks everyone for the contributions!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).